# Powerapps Flows not triggering after move to managed environment

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, power-automate

Just imported multiple flows into a managed production environment and now they are not being triggered (JotForm triggers). All connections are correct. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: As you mentioned all connections are correct, Could you check if they are turned On. Sometimes during Import they tend of be off.

Also sometimes flow connections ask for permission. Could you go to each of the flow and check if that is not the case.

Comment: did you managed to resolve it?

Comment: Figured that part out but my imported solution is still not showing changes that were made unless unmanaged layers are removed